# Parsing markdown in C++ : The case of html ordered list

Tags: html, c++, parsing, markdown

I'm working on a regex based markdown parser in C++ for a future markdown text editor for myself.
I'm kind of new in the regex world and when confronted with ordered list, i have this problem where i can't really replace markdown text into proper html code.

### Code Snippet :

```cpp
std::regex olRegex(R"(^\s*\d+\.\s+(.*)$)", std::regex_constants::multiline);

std::regex nestedOlRegex(R"(^\s{4,}\d+\.\s+(.*)$)", std::regex_constants::multiline);

// Replace ordered lists with HTML <ol> tags
std::string parsed_text  = std::regex_replace(md_text, olRegex, "<ol>\n$&\n</ol>");

// Replace nested ordered lists with HTML <ol> tags within <li> tags
parsed_text  = std::regex_replace(parsed_text , nestedOlRegex, "<ol>\n$&\n</ol>");

// Replace list items with HTML <li> tags
parsed_text  = std::regex_replace(parsed_text , std::regex(R"(^\s*\d+\.\s+(.*)$)", std::regex_constants::multiline), "<li>$1</li>");

    return parsed_text ;
```

### Markdown TestString :

```markdown
# Heading 1

## Heading 2
This is a paragraph with some **bold** and *italic* text.

There is also some ~~strikethrough~~ text.

And also ***bold italic*** text.

* Unordered List Item 1
    * Nested Unordered List Item 1
    * Nested Unordered List Item 2
        * This is too much
* Unordered List Item 2

1. Ordered List Item 1
2. Ordered List Item 2
    1. Nested Ordered List Item 1
    2. Nested Ordered List Item 2
        1. This is too much

* this is maybe working
    1. this is not working

- [x] Task 1
- [ ] Task 2
  - [ ] Too much task
    - [x] Too much to ask 

![Alt text](image.jpg)

[Link Text](https://www.example.com)
```

### Problem :

In this code, each time i encounter a ordered list, i replace each line by it's equivalent html code. In my case, each line of the ordered list fall into the olRegex or nestedOlRegex case and the beacon

is set to the new line. Leading to this html page where number in front of the line aren't considered:

[rendered markdown html text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHhrE.png)

And this hell of a monster of html :

```html
<ol>
<li>Ordered List Item 1</li>
</ol>
<ol>
<li>Ordered List Item 2</li>
</ol>
<ol>
<ol>
<li>Nested Ordered List Item 1</li>
</ol>
</ol>
<ol>
<ol>
<li>Nested Ordered List Item 2</li>
</ol>
</ol>
<ol>
<ol>
<li>This is too much</li>
</ol>
</ol>
<ul>
<li>this is maybe working</li>
</ul>
<ol>
<ol>
<li>this is not working</li>
</ol>
</ol>
```

### Expectation :

I guess the wanted hmtl should be like this with only one

beacon :

```
<ol>
<li>Ordered List Item 1</li>
<li>Ordered List Item 2</li>
<ol>
<li>Nested Ordered List Item 1</li>
<li>Nested Ordered List Item 2</li>
<ol>
<li>This is too much</li>
</ol>
</ol>
</ol>
```

### What could be done :

Maybe it exist a more iterative / recursive approach where i can set only once for each layer of nested list the correct beacon but i don't really find information online.

For me the most important thing is the maximum 2 layer of nested list and the correct ordering of each line.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Relying on regular expressions for parsing and intelligently handling nested structures is a losing battle. Even if you can nail it down, your expression becomes difficult to read and maintain. You're far better off using the regular expressions to tokenize your data, but then handle the actual state and output logic in code.

Comment: Unless this is just for fun and exercise, please don't do this. Use an existing library or application to do it for you.

Comment: You can not transform between two structured data formats with search and replace (besides some simple lucky cases). You have to parse the hierarchy of data in and output it back in different format.